# Rails - How to create a 'previous page' object/method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

How can I obtain the path of the previous page so I can use it in an if-statement like so:

```
if previous_page == example_path
   ...
else
   ...
end
```

Edit:

For clarification, I'm setting custom redirects for User Updates with Devise. The redirects go through a method called `after_update_path_for(resource)` and I'm adding playing around with that.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with the referer from the request object in your controllers.

```
request.referer
=> http://localhost:3000/contacts
```

Comment: You can use request.headers["HTTP_REFERER"] too.

Answer (score -1):

Use the session to store the current page, so that you can check later (on the next page) which one it was.